# difference between :: and -> in calling class's function in php

Tags: php, class, function

I have seen function called from php classes with :: or ->.

eg:

$classinstance::function
 or
$classinstance->function

whats the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `::` syntax means that you are calling a [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) method.  Whereas the `->` is non-static.

```
MyClass{

  public function myFun(){  
  }

  public static function myStaticFun(){
  }

}

$obj = new MyClass();

// Notice how the two methods must be called using different syntax
$obj->myFun();
MyClass::myStaticFun();
```

Comment: This is not strictly true. You can call static methods with `->` (though you shouldn't, but it doesn't even through a strict warning) and you can use `::` to call instance methods (which you either must, as in `parent::parentImplementationOfThisMethods()` or you really shouldn't as in `$obj::myFun()`).

Answer (score 2):

`::` is used for [scope resolution](http://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php), accessing (typically) *static* methods, variables, or constants, whereas `->` is used for [invoking object methods or accessing object properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) on a particular object instance.

In other words, the typical syntax is...

```
ClassName::MemberName
```

versus...

```
$Instance->MemberName
```

In the rare cases where you see `$variable::MemberName`, what's actually going on there is that the contents of `$variable` are treated *as a class name*, so `$var='Foo'; $var::Bar` is equivalent to `Foo::Bar`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

http://www.php.net/manual/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
class FooBar {
    public function sayHi() { echo 'Hi!'; }
    public /* --> */ static /* <-- */ function sayHallo() { echo 'Hallo!'; }
}

// object call (needs an instance, $foobar here)
$foobar = new FooBar;
$foobar->sayHi();

// static class call, no instance required
FooBar::sayHallo(); // notice I use the plain classname here, not $foobar!

// As of PHP 5.3 you can write:
$nameOfClass = 'FooBar'; // now I store the classname in a variable
$nameOfClass::sayHallo(); // and call it statically

$foobar::sayHallo(); // This will not work, because $foobar is an class *instance*, not a class *name*
```

Answer (score 0):

::function is for static functions, and should actually be used as:

class::function() rather than $instance::function() as you suggest.

You can also use

class::function()

in a subclass to refer to parent's methods.

Answer (score 0):

[`::`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) is normally used for calling [static](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) methods or [Class Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php). (in other words, you don't need to instantiate the object with `new`) in order to use the method. And `->` is when you've already instantiated a object.

For example:

```
Validation::CompareValues($val1, $val2);

$validation = new Validation;
$validation->CompareValues($val1, $val2);
```

As a note, any method you try to use as static (or with `::`) must have the static keyword used when defining it. Read the various PHP.net documentation pages I've linked to in this post.

Answer (score 0):

With `::` you can access constants, attributes or methods of a **class**; the variables and methods need to be declared as static, otherwise they do belong to an instance and not to the class.

And with `->` you can access attributes or methods of an **instance of a class**.